# Is TextTrimming= "WordEllipsis" Supported in WP7 or Not?

Tags: windows-phone-7, texttrimming

I'm trying to suffix an ellipsis when the contents in the textbox is too long, but I can't find a "TextTrimming" property in the WP7 framework. Is there some other property to perform the same function? For example:

"If the sentence is too big, I want it to end with a ..."

Answer (score 4):

Robby Ingebretsen's [TextTrimming TextBlock for Silverlight](http://nerdplusart.com/texttrimming-textblock-for-silverlight) works well in WP7.

Answer (score 2):

The TextTrimming property of the TextBlock is supported in the Mango version of the SDK.